# Type safe `as const` with Typescript

Tags: typescript

When I define an object like this, it accepts any `string` as a key to the object even if it does not exist.

I would like some sort of way to receive an error like `Property 'x' doesn't exist on FIELD_DEFS` while maintaining type safety of the contents of the boject such as `myKey: {...}`

```
export const FIELD_DEFS: {
  [fieldKey: string]: FieldObj;
} = { 
   myKey: { ... }
};
```

As an alternate I can do:

```
export const FIELD_DEFS = { 
    myKey: { ... } satisfies FieldObj
} as const
```

But it's more verbose and in this case `FIELD_DEFS` is quite large

Comment: `FIELD_DEFS = {} as const satisfies Record<string, FieldObj>` ?

Comment: Works!! @wonderflame could you add that as the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `satisfies` per field, you can combine it with [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
type FieldObj= {
  name: string
}

const FIELD_DEFS = {
  myKey: {
    name: 'string'
  }
} as const satisfies Record<string, FieldObj>
```